# ListView max height

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

So, my problem is: if there are to many elements in `#picture` listView the button `Add image` goes off-screen.
I just want `Add image` button at it's the lowest border ran into `Next` button.
Should I calculate max height for `header_layout` or there is another way to solve it?

pseudo code looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/blue"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
               ... ID
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                ... Owner
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                ...Date
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="#pictures"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listview_images"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_add_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:text="Add image"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And view:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pRrm.png)

Comment: Why do you use linear layouts inside the constraint layout?
This could be solved using only ConstraintLayout

Comment: not related to your question really, but you shouldn't be using a listView anymore

Comment: Yeah use recyclerview

Comment: If you want to stick with linear layouts use android:layout_weight

Comment: Add android:layout_weight="1" to your #header_layout arguments

Answer (score 0):

Add android:layout_weight="1" to your #header_layout

Comment: i think this answer would be great if you showed a solution using constraint layout as well considering it actually is the root layout

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in this case it is actually not possible to completelly rely on ConstrainLayout.
You could do smth like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_next"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_next"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:text="ID:"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_owner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:text="Owner:"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:text="Date: 03/11/2020 11:40"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:text="#pictures"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/listview_images"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_add_picture"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="Add image" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```